# How do I select all the text in a WPF textbox on click

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have several TextBoxes within a UniformGrid.

I want to select all the within a textbox when it is clicked I'd rather the event came from the uniformgrid. I was able to implement selecting all the text with GotKeyboardFocus for when I use only the keyboard with the code below in the handler. However when I merely click on the box it highlights while my mouse is down and on mouse up the cursor appears rather than the text remaining selected.

```
    foreach(TextBox Box in grid.Children)
    {
        if (Box.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
        {
            Box.SelectAll();
            e.Handled = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

I also have an PreviewKeyUp handler that watches for a max number of letters then moves to the next box. Also each box is initialized with the max number of letters when the screen loads. Which is why I want to do a select all on the text in the textbox so it can be typed over easily.

I was able to use GotMouseCapture almost perfectly except that it doesn't work if you click near the text only near the edge of the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try hooking up to the `PreviewMouseUp` routed event. That worked for me.

Comment: I believe I tried that and once I clicked it got stuck on that textbox... I'l give it a fresh go in the morning though!